# Using pycrypto appengine with python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycrypto

What's the best way to protect a symmetric key that needs to be used in code within Google Appengine?

Our application uses Python 2.7

EDIT: we have some database fields that we want protected, that need to be accessed in the code but there is no reason to leave them in the database in plain text. Obviously I'd like to make it as hard as possible to retrieve the key (understanding that it is never impossible).

Comment: Protect because you don't want it in the code or you don't want tgat some Googler will peek into your app and see it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to absolutely protect a key if you don't trust the environment that the code is running in. You could store (part of) the key in a trusted location and only accept queries for the key from the domain/IP of your app. But then it would still be in that appengine instance's memory.

The best solution for outgoing messages is to use public-key crypto. Let your code use the public key of the remote party, since those don't have to be kept secret. It can then only be decrypted with the remote's private key.

If you can't trust the appengine's environment, you can't decrypt incoming public-key messages because that would require your secret key to be available to the application.

Edit: Since you've added that you want to protect some database fields, have you thought about [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) them?

Comment: thanks for your answer. There's no perfect way to protect any key in security, every system has vulnerabilities. I'm more looking the 'best' method. For example, I'd think storing the key only in memory is better than having it in the source code as it increases the difficulty of retrieving it.

Comment: Isn't that just replacing the problem with another? If you want to have the key in memory but not on disk it means you have to retrieve it from another secure location, by a secure method. That means two extra problems. :-) If you don't trust Google Appengine (and I'm not saying you should or shouldn't), don't use it.

Comment: Hi Roland, you could modify the appengine deployment script so you enter a secret when you deploy code. This will live in memory for the deployed code and even if your application code is compromised the data won't be. Although still not perfect, I would consider this a more secure situation than leaving the secret in the source code. I trust the environment but that doesn't mean precautions shouldn't be taken where possible.

Comment: Hi Richard. I'm having a hard time thinking up an actual threat scenario where you aren't toast. :-) If someone gets access to your appengine instance, by whatever means (stealing your credentials, "turning" someone within google, etc), he can presumably intercept your secret when you're inputting it. Google could log _everything_ you do without you noticing it. And if the attacker _really_ wants that secret, there is always rubber hose cryptanalysis. :-( To use a typed-in password or secret safely, _I_ would want to type it in on the console of the server that runs the app!

Comment: Absolutely if someone gains access to the instance they can dump the memory and get the key (with either console or deployment script password). Same with a rubber hose. No secret can be protected completely and security is all about finding the best compromise. Our source code and application data live in many places, our server instances live in one so we're reducing the attack space by only putting the secret there and trusting Google to do a 'reasonable' job of protecting it. Unfortunately hashing the data won't allow it to be recovered which is a requirement.

Comment: What you could do is put a couple of blocks of random data in the datastore and use those to generate the in-memory key. E.g. by XOR-ing the random data and then cranking it through a key derivation function like PBKDF2 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or scrypt (http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html). This would mean that both the datastore and the source code have to be compromised for an attacker to get the key and so access to the data.